# Webform entity reference view?

Tags: views, webforms

I want to have a field to select a webforms within a paragraph using an entity reference field in the "Views: Filter by an entity reference view" reference mode, so that I can reduce the number of options particular authors see.

However, "webform" is not a valid selection when I go to create a view. I see "webform submissions" but not "webform." Is there a different webform submodule that I have to turn on, I am puzzled why this is not available, so wonder if something is going on on my site.

(This is on a Drupal 9.5 site, using webform 6.1.3)

- The webform_views module does not seem to provide the integration which is what I would expect. It also seems to be related to submissions.
- I thought I could use that module to create an Entity Reference list of views from the submissions, using a relationships (submitted to: content) and then aggregating on the individual forms. This works except that in order to work it has to be attached to an entity already (the submitted to content).

Comment: Is this because Webforms are configuration entities?

Comment: Ah, yeah that makes some sense. Will give this a try https://www.drupal.org/project/config_view

Comment: Alas. My site did not like that config_view module (at least locally) out of memory errors :-(

Comment: "I want to have a field to select a webforms within a paragraph" - Webform does provide a webform field which allows you to select forms. It's a special kind of entity reference field that references webforms. It's pretty basic, no programmatic/contextual filtering. You can select which forms appear iirc. You might want to play with it to get what you need. See `\Drupal\webform\Plugin\Field\FieldType\WebformEntityReferenceItem`

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I am using that field, but it shows all the forms for all users. There isn't a way to select the forms to choose from. Thanks for the pointer to the plugin though. Will see if I can manage anything with that.

Comment: Oh, actually, I do now see where you can choose the forms to select. It is on the "Manage Form Display" page. That doesn't solve my use case where I only want to show them their own webforms, but might be handy in other instances.